# SWF showing up empty in FlashDevelop?

Tags: actionscript, flash, flashdevelop, swc

I am a beginner with Flash, and I am having issues with FlashDevelop.
I have created my animation and published it and I received my fla, swf, and swc (and they all look to be okay) and I copied them to my FlashDevelop lib and bin folders. And when they are added I can double click on my swf and see my swf, but when I click the play button on my project the window that opens is empty. And then when I check back on my swf it is now empty. I think my code in my .as files is fine, since it throws zero errors and it is really basic.

Is there any reason why my swf would just show up blank after I run it in FlashDevelop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, your SWF file is named the same as your project... so when you 'play' it in FlashDevelop, it is compiling your AS code and overwriting your original SWF file with a new, blank SWF file. So, basically I think its a naming issue - call your SWF something else.

But, beyond that... I'm not sure what you are trying to do; I have a feeling you are expecting something that FlashDevelop is not going to do.